# DateDiff error, "The expression is not complete"

Tags: date, datediff, tibco, spotfire

In Spotfire I am using below expression using custom expression to make a horizontal line but I am getting error: `"The expression is not complete"`. I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

```
DateDiff('dd',${startDate},${endDate})
```

Where `startDate` & `endDate` are document properties of "Date Time" type set to values "1/1/2013 12:00 AM" & "2/4/2013 12:00 AM" respectively.

I am getting following expression in "Resulting expression" tab:

```
DateDiff('dd',01/01/2013 00:00:00,02/04/2013 00:00:00)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the expression you have 2 options on how to insert a document property, one of them is to insert the property as text which is what you have done by entering the expression:

```
DateDiff('dd',${startDate},${endDate})
```

the other option, and the one you need, is to insert the property as a value which is achieved thus:

```
DateDiff("dd",DocumentProperty("startDate"),DocumentProperty("endDate"))
```

If you don't think you'll remember this then you can always right click on the property when creating your expression and the 2 options will be shown to you and inserted automatically depending on your selection:

[image: Spotfire Custom Expression]

Notice as well that nothing is shown in the Resulting expression box.

Here is a quick test I done, my date data is Date rather than DateTime but it works just the same:

[image: Example data]

Further information can be gained [in the Spotfire documentation](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/prop/prop_properties_in_expressions.htm).